# Filtrar registros Por Mes en laravel ( sin eloquent)

Tags: laravel

tengo una vista en la cual debo mostrar en una tabla unos resultados que deben estar agrupados por el mes, es decir por ejemplo mostrar un titulo Enero y abajo en la tabla todos los resultados de la consulta filtrados por el mes, hasta ahora tengo la tabla en la vista así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la Base de Datos, el tipo de campo de la fecha_ingreso es de tipo DATE.

La función que tengo en el controlador (y que me retorna los datos que se muestran en la tabla) es esta:

```
public function detalleSeriesArticulos($bodega_id, $servicio_id){

        $detalle = DB::table('ingreso_materials as ingreso')
        ->join('det_ingreso_materials as detalle' , 'detalle.ingreso_material_id', 'ingreso.id')
        ->join('materials as material' , 'material.id' , 'detalle.material_id')
        ->join('bodegas as bodega' , 'bodega.id' , 'detalle.bodega_id')
        ->join('servicios as servicio' , 'servicio.id' , 'detalle.servicio_id')
        ->join('proveedors as proveedor' , 'proveedor.id' , 'material.proveedor_id')
        ->join('serializacions as serializacion' , 'serializacion.ingreso_material_id' , 'ingreso.id')
        ->join('det_serializacions as detSerializacion' , 'detSerializacion.serializacion_id' , 'serializacion.id')

        ->select('ingreso.id', 'ingreso.num_guia_despacho', 'ingreso.fecha_ingreso', 'detalle.cantidad', 'servicio.servicio',
        'bodega.nombre_bodega','material.nombre_producto', 'proveedor.razon_social', 'proveedor.rut_proveedor',
        'detSerializacion.serie', 'detSerializacion.mac')
        ->where('detalle.bodega_id' , $bodega_id)
        ->where('detalle.servicio_id' , $servicio_id)
        ->get();

        return response()->json( $detalle, 200);
    }
```

Basicamente tengo dudas en como haria el filtro en el controlador, MI idea para que sea mas facil y mas visual seria añadir un select con el listado de meses y que al seleccionar un mes me cargue la tabla filtrada...

Saludos a todos

Comment: Podés usar whereMonth y whereYear https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses . Prueba algo y si te encontrás con algún problema puntual actualiza la pregunta

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ gracias por el link, creo que ahi esta la clave, no vi esa parte en la documentacion jeje

Comment: Vale. En esa página también podés leer sobre consultas condicionales, para el caso del select que mencionas